# If and why the CSS should be put outside the react function components(near the imports)?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I just meet a problem that could not load the CSS inside react function component with material UI. Though I fixed it, I am still curious about the reason.
In the beginning, I write something like this, where I put both makeStyles and useStyles inside the function component. Then, I find that the class name is correctly assigned to the element, but no css is loaded.

```
import makeStyles from "material-UI"
import styles from "styles.js"

export default function alertPage() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [alert, setalert] = React.useState();
  const showAlert = () => {
    setalert(<p className={classes.text}></p>)
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={showAlert}></button>
    {alert}
  )
}
```

Then, I put makeStyles outside the function, everything works correctly.

```
import makeStyles from "material-UI"
import styles from "styles.js"

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function alertPage() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [alert, setalert] = React.useState();
  const showAlert = () => {
    setalert(<p className={classes.text}></p>)
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={showAlert}></button>
    {alert}
  )
}
```

Then, I tried this code putting both inside function component again, but return the HTML directly, which still works.

```
import makeStyles from "material-UI"
import styles from "styles.js"

export default function alertPage() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <p className={classes.text}></p>
  )
}
```

Then, I check the react official site and find that they always put CSS outside the function component, but not getting any sentences mentioned that this is required or why.
My guess is that I misunderstand the scope of the const or how CSS is actually loaded in the browser. If anybody could tell me the reason, or which piece of knowledge I missed, like js, ts, react, or how the browser works?
Thanks!

Comment: What is it you think is *inside* a react hook? `useStyles` is the only hook in your snippet and if I had to guess, placing the `makeStyles` hook generator inside the render body the hook is redeclared each render cycle. Why are you storing JSX in component state? This is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks for the reply. I am sorry that I just pick up a react template for work without any knowledge, so I thought the function component is the same as the hook, which misleads u. The setState will only be called when a button is clicked, to make the code short, I just put it in the declaration directly. If u are saying I should put JSX in return, but use boolean to control it shows or not? Return to the question,  the third code snippet works, so I think redeclare may not be the direct reason. It looks like the declaration is always written outside, maybe the origin of the bug.

Comment: The third snippet is the closest to being correct, but you should move the `useStyles` declaration *outside* the component. @Josh answered below. Also, what boolean value are you referring to? Are you saying there is more to your use case and you are wanting to conditionally render some UI in this component?

Comment: @DrewReese, yes conditionally render some UI. The first code snippet just follows the template writing style and meets the bug. Then, I spend a long time to find that I did not put the makeStyles outside the function component, which is also in the template. After putting the makeStyles outside the function component, it works well (the second code snipped). Then, I find the third code snipped works and be confused. I understand how to correct coding now, but just a bit curious about what actually happened.

Comment: Well, the first two snippets aren't quite valid JSX, and the third hasn't any conditional rendering nor any state updates so there are no rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), you should have something like the below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
     // Your styles
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  // Rest of your code
}
```

If you have styles in a correctly formatted import, you should be able to add them directly in the `makeStyles` declaration:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is why I put makeStyles inside the export function, the classes could be used in return directly, but the css is not correctly loaded if the JSX is added later like the code snippet.